# Convert double to string with more than 5 decimal digit precision

Tags: c++, string, double, type-conversion, precision

At first I used boost's `lexical_cast` to do this. But due to the way C++ represents doubles/floats, when I converted `5.1` to a string it would give me `5.0999999` or something to that extent. So, I converted it this way:

```
stringstream ss;
ss << 3.14159265359;
cout << ss.str();
```

But this would only give me `3.14159`, and I would like more precision than that. I think I saw something about `printf()` being able to do this, but I am actually working on a Windows GUI program, not outputting to a console. How can I get more than 5 decimal digits of precision? I am willing to settle for 8, but 10 or 11 would be nice. Is this too much to ask for given how C++ represents floats and doubles?

Comment: As you can see in [the Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/synopsis.html), `lexical_cast` and your code use the same technique.

Comment: Then why is it they produce different results?

Comment: Because `boost::lexical_cast` invokes `ss.precision()` and you don't.

Comment: FYI, useful link: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill19.htm

Comment: Actually, I made that comment After I had saw the answer involving `setprecision`. Mine was producing different results. Then I started messing with the `setprecision` parameter, and at high values I get the very same behavior, so I see what you mean. Therefor I'm not so sure about my answer anymore.

Comment: I think I just shouldn't try setting the precision higher than 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ss << setprecision(12) << 3.14159265359;
```

Also, the choice between using streams and the C `printf`/`scanf` family has nothing to do with GUI vs. console.  The C equivalent of `ostringstream` is `sprintf`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not entirely too familiar with stringstream manipulation. And I see, I thought `printf` was similar to using `cout` except with formatting.